# Optimizing neon assembly functions

Tags: android, c, native, inline-assembly, neon

I am working on a native android app that should run on a ARMv7 processor device.
For some reasons I need to do some heavy computation on vectors (short and/or float).
I implemented some assembly function using NEON commands to boost the computation. I have gained a 1.5 speed factor which is not bad. I am wondering if I can improve these functions to go even faster.

So the question is: what changes can I do to improve these functions ?

```
    //add to float vectors.
//the result could be put in scr1 instead of dst
void add_float_vector_with_neon3(float* dst, float* src1, float* src2, int count)
{

    asm volatile (
           "1:                                                        \n"
           "vld1.32         {q0}, [%[src1]]!                          \n"
           "vld1.32         {q1}, [%[src2]]!                          \n"
           "vadd.f32        q0, q0, q1                                \n"
           "subs            %[count], %[count], #4                    \n"
           "vst1.32         {q0}, [%[dst]]!                           \n"
           "bgt             1b                                        \n"
           : [dst] "+r" (dst)
           : [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2), [count] "r" (count)
           : "memory", "q0", "q1"
      );
}

//multiply a float vector by a scalar.
//the result could be put in scr1 instead of dst
void mul_float_vector_by_scalar_with_neon3(float* dst, float* src1, float scalar, int count)
{

    asm volatile (

            "vdup.32         q1, %[scalar]                              \n"
            "2:                                                         \n"
            "vld1.32         {q0}, [%[src1]]!                           \n"
            "vmul.f32        q0, q0, q1                                 \n"
            "subs            %[count], %[count], #4                     \n"
            "vst1.32         {q0}, [%[dst]]!                            \n"
            "bgt             2b                                         \n"
            : [dst] "+r" (dst)
            : [src1] "r" (src1), [scalar] "r" (scalar), [count] "r" (count)
            : "memory", "q0", "q1"
      );
}

//add to short vector -> no problem of coding limits
//the result should be put in in a dest different from src1 and scr2
void add_short_vector_with_neon3(short* dst, short* src1, short* src2, int count)
{

    asm volatile (
           "3:                                                        \n"
           "vld1.16         {q0}, [%[src1]]!                          \n"
           "vld1.16         {q1}, [%[src2]]!                          \n"
           "vadd.i16        q0, q0, q1                                \n"
           "subs            %[count], %[count], #8                    \n"
           "vst1.16         {q0}, [%[dst]]!                           \n"
           "bgt             3b                                        \n"
           : [dst] "+r" (dst)
           : [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2), [count] "r" (count)
           : "memory", "q0", "q1"
      );
}

//multiply a short vector by a float vector and put the result bach into a short vector
//the result should be put in in a dest different from src1
void mul_short_vector_by_float_vector_with_neon3(short* dst, short* src1, float* src2, int count)
{
    asm volatile (
        "4:                                                         \n"
        "vld1.16        {d0}, [%[src1]]!                            \n"
        "vld1.32        {q1}, [%[src2]]!                            \n"
        "vmovl.s16      q0, d0                                      \n"
        "vcvt.f32.s32   q0, q0                                      \n"
        "vmul.f32       q0, q0, q1                                  \n"
        "vcvt.s32.f32   q0, q0                                      \n"
        "vmovn.s32      d0, q0                                      \n"
        "subs            %[count], %[count], #4                     \n"
        "vst1.16         {d0}, [%[dst]]!                            \n"
        "bgt             4b                                         \n"
        : [dst] "+r" (dst)
        : [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2), [count] "r" (count)
        : "memory", "d0", "q0", "q1"

    );
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well this is assembly not intrinsics

Comment: Thanks, I changed the post

Comment: I found a ton of useful tips at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/12/12/from-arm-neon-to-intel-mmxsse-automatic-porting-solution-tips-and-tricks

Comment: first rule of thumb is that don't try to use the result from load immediately after a load, as load takes time and can stall the next instruction. so you always want to interleave the instructions, or `software-pipeline` the instructions.

Comment: I don't speak ARM. At all. But I do worry a bit about this code due to this line from the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands): `Warning: Do not modify the contents of input-only operands (except for inputs tied to outputs)`. To clarify this restriction, will the register that contains 'count' have exactly the same value when it exits the asm as it did when it entered? If the answer is no, you have violated the rule. Bad things may result if gcc tries to re-use a register that it 'knows' contains a particular value, only to find that you have misled it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try unrolling your loop to process more elements per loop.

Your code for add_float_vector_with_neon3 takes 10 cycles (because of stalling) per 4 elements, while unrolling to 16 elements consumes 21 cycles.
http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/sample-34e5f701

Though there is a overhead because you need to process the remainder (or you can pad your data to be multiple of 16), but if you have lots of data, the overhead should be fairly low compared to the actual sum.

Comment: Hi, That's a nice reply ! Both the tool that is pointed http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php and the technic that is proposed.I don't have remainders (512 values per vector) but many vectors to add.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how you can code it with neon instrinsics.

The advantage is that you can use the compiler to optimize register allocation and instruction scheduling while constrain the instruction usage.

The downside is that, GCC doesn't seem able to combine the pointer arithmetic into the load/store instruction so additional ALU instructions are issued to do it. Or maybe I'm wrong and GCC has a good reason of doing it that way.

With GCC and `CFLAGS=-std=gnu11 -O3 -fgcse-lm -fgcse-sm -fgcse-las -fgcse-after-reload -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -fPIE -Wall` this code compiles to very decent object code. Loop is unrolled and interleaved to hide the long delay before the result of a load is available. And it's also readable, too.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

#define ASSUME_ALIGNED_FLOAT_128(ptr) ((float *)__builtin_assume_aligned((ptr), 16))

__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))
void add_float_vector_with_neon3(      float *restrict dst,
                                 const float *restrict src1,
                                 const float *restrict src2, 
                                 size_t size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i+=4){
        float32x4_t inFloat41  = vld1q_f32(ASSUME_ALIGNED_FLOAT_128(src1));
        float32x4_t inFloat42  = vld1q_f32(ASSUME_ALIGNED_FLOAT_128(src2));
        float32x4_t outFloat64 = vaddq_f32 (inFloat41, inFloat42);
        vst1q_f32 (ASSUME_ALIGNED_FLOAT_128(dst), outFloat64);
        src1+=4;
        src2+=4;
        dst+=4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will compare the two functions (assembly VS intrinsics). I will give feedback on the performances.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have compilation troubles using intrinsics in my code. I receive a "vld1q_f32 could not be resolved".

Comment: @MadMax007 Intrinsics isn't worth your time if you already can write in assembly which you do. Just unroll your loop, the performance will more than double.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I compared between the code given in the initial post and a new function proposed by Josejulio:

```
void add_float_vector_with_neon3(float* dst, float* src1, float* src2, int count)
{
    asm volatile (
            "1:                                 \n"
            "vld1.32 {q0,q1}, [%[src1]]!        \n"
            "vld1.32 {q2,q3}, [%[src2]]!        \n"
            "vadd.f32 q0, q0, q2                \n"
            "vadd.f32 q1, q1, q3                \n"
            "vld1.32 {q4,q5}, [%[src1]]!        \n"
            "vld1.32 {q6,q7}, [%[src2]]!        \n"
            "vadd.f32 q4, q4, q6                \n"
            "vadd.f32 q5, q5, q7                \n"
            "subs %[count], %[count], #16       \n"
            "vst1.32 {q0, q1}, [%[dst]]!        \n"
            "vst1.32 {q4, q5}, [%[dst]]!        \n"
            "bgt             1b                 \n"
            : [dst] "+r" (dst)
            : [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2), [count] "r" (count)
            : "memory", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7"
      );
}
```

Whereas in the tool (pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php), there is a big difference in CPU cylcles/float, I don't see much difference in latency checking:

median, firstQuartile, thirdQuartile, minVal, maxVal (micro-sec, 1000 measures)

original: 3564, 3206, 5126, 1761, 12144

unrolled: 3567, 3080, 4877, 3018, 11683

So I am not sure that the unrollment is so efficient...